# change pdftk encoding. Cyrillic display

Tags: php, pdftk

I'm using pdftk to fill out a PDF form with fields. Numbers and Latin characters are filled in without problems, but when I try to fill in the form with a value using Cyrillic, I get ... (see picture). In the MySQL database, Cyrillic values are stored in cells with `utf8_general_ci` encoding. How can I fix the Cyrillic display?

[image]

Comment: What is the encoding of the PDF? If it _is_ UTF8, then I would suspect that the font you're using does not have glyphs for Cyrillic. That said, you're not likely to get much in the way of workable answers without showing any code.

Comment: @Sammitch the encoding is not PDF, but the data that I retrieve from the database and use to fill. In addition, I use the standard font Times New Roman, which is used throughout the document (the form itself was created using it, everything works as it should with Cyrillic)

Comment: Looks like a problem with fonts missing cyrillic glyphs. I'm not familiar with pdftk, so can't give any specific instructions, but worth looking into its documentation. The fonts might need to be installed in the OS, rather than somewhere in the app.

Comment: @astax font selection is set to Adobe Acrobat DC. With the same font, when filling out the form manually, there are no problems, the Cyrillic in the forms is displayed correctly. Despite this, I will still check the performance with a different font and report back on the result.